# generate logical matrix in R

Tags: r

I need to generate a logical matrix in R for the project that I am working on.It should be such that the diagonals should be TRUE rest is FALSE.  For 2x2 matrix it was simple.

```
 d_matrix=matrix(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,TRUE),nrow=2,byrow=TRUE)
 d_matrix
       [,1]  [,2]
 [1,]  TRUE FALSE
 [2,] FALSE  TRUE
     n=20
  diag_mat=diag(TRUE,n)
```

Now I have come across a problem where I need such logical matrix for any n. Say      n=20. I tried as shown above but it gave me a matrix of 0 and 1's in diagonal.But I need TRUE and FALSE. Is there any way to do this so that I get matrix like d_matrix for any given n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do a `diag` and convert it to `logical` matrix

```
fmat <- function(n) {
            diag(n)==1
    }
fmat(2)
#     [,1]  [,2]
#[1,]  TRUE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thats awesome. Thanks !